# Jquery on change function pass value using ajax to database file .but working only first time

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, filtering

Jquery On Change function working only first when i passing the value using ajax jquery function to database file using select box.but working only first time second time when i change the value of selected box .its not working why please help code are given below.

```
if(isset($package_sort ) && !empty($package_sort ))
 {




switch ($package_sort) {

    case "1000":
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE package_city='goa' AND package_price ORDER BY package_price ASC";   

        break;
    case "160000":
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE package_city='goa' AND package_price <=".$_GET['package_sort']." ORDER BY package_price DESC";   

        break;
    default:
        echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
}

<script>  

    $(function(){  
   $(document).on('change', '#package_sort', function(){  
           var package_sort = $(this).val();


           $.ajax({  
                url:"package-search.php",  
                method:"GET",  
                data:{package_sort:package_sort},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $("#package_loading").fadeIn(500).html(data);  
                }  

           });  
      });  
    });
    </script>  
<div class="select-wrapper"><select name="package_sort1" id="package_sort" class="custom-select selectbox">
                                                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" hidden="hidden">Sort By</option>
                                                        <option value="1000" name="package_sort">Low to Height</option>
                                                        <option value="160000" name="package_sort">Height to Low</option>

                                                    </select></div>
```

Comment: try this `$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#package_sort").change(function(){
        alert("change");
    });
});` check alert.

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined the variable `$package_sort`. Also you need to check the `$_GET` is set or not

```
if(isset($_GET['package_sort']) && !empty($_GET['package_sort'] )){
    $package_sort = $_GET['package_sort'];
    switch ($package_sort) {

        case "1000":
           $sql = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE package_city='goa' AND package_price ORDER BY package_price ASC";   

            break;
        case "160000":
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM package WHERE package_city='goa' AND package_price <=".$_GET['package_sort']." ORDER BY package_price DESC";   

            break;
        default:
            echo "Your favorite color is neither red, blue, nor green!";
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also store the value $_GET['package_sort'] in  $package_sort

Comment: jquery code -<script>  
 
 $(function(){  
   $(document).on('change', '#package_sort', function(){  
           var package_sort = $(this).val();

            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"package-search.php",  
                method:"GET",  
                data:{package_sort:package_sort},  
                success:function(data){  
                     $("#package_loading").fadeIn(500).html(data);  
                }  
    
           });  
     
      });  
 });
 </script>